# Django Rest Framework: Writable nested serializers with Generic Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

There are examples how to create a writable nested serializer like [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) and then how to serialize a generic foreign key ([here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships)).

But I cannot find how to do both at the same time, i.e how to create a nested writable serializer for a generic foreign key field.

In my models there is a `Meeting` model with a `GenericForeignKey` which can be either `DailyMeeting` or `WeeklyMeeting` like:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    # More fields above
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    recurring_meeting = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class DailyMeeting(models.Model):
    meeting = GenericRelation(Meeting)
    # more fields

class WeeklyMeeting(models.Model):
    meeting = GenericRelation(Meeting)
    # more fields
```

Then I created a custom field in my `serializers.py`:

```
class RecurringMeetingRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, DailyMeeting):
            serializer = DailyMeetingSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, WeeklyMeeting):
            serializer = WeeklyMeetingSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
        return serializer.data


class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recurring_meeting = RecurringMeetingRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am passing a JSON which looks like:

```
{
    "start_time": "2017-11-27T18:50:00",
    "end_time": "2017-11-27T21:30:00",
    "subject": "Test now",
    "moderators": [41],
    "recurring_meeting":{
        "interval":"daily",
        "repetitions": 10,
        "weekdays_only": "True"
        }
}
```

But the problem is that I am getting the following error:

> AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Why does the Relational field has to be `read_only`? If I set it as `read_only` then it is not passed in the `data` in the serializer.

And what type of queryset do I have to provide?

Comment: I had not checked the scenario but you dont have to pass the recurring_meeting from the api.. (Its added in the serializer create() Method) so you can set ```read_only```

Comment: If you set it as ``read_only`` there is nothing in the ``validated_data`` passed to the ``create()`` method. So, in this case the recurring_meeting is totally ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement `to_internal_value` as well, and you can use just plain `Field` class.

```
from rest_framework.fields import Field

class RecurringMeetingRelatedField(Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, DailyMeeting):
            serializer = DailyMeetingSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, WeeklyMeeting):
            serializer = WeeklyMeetingSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
        return serializer.data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # you need to pass some identity to figure out which serializer to use
        # supose you'll add 'meeting_type' key to your json
        meeting_type = data.pop('meeting_type')

        if meeting_type == 'daily':
            serializer = DailyMeetingSerializer(data)
        elif meeting_type == 'weekly':
            serializer = WeeklyMeetingSerializer(data)
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('no meeting_type provided')

        if serializer.is_valid():
            obj = serializer.save()
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(serializer.errors)

        return obj
```

If validation went well then you'll get created object in the `MeetingSerializer` validated data in other case `RecurringMeetingRelatedField` will raise an exception.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! I just found that when I update the whole ``meeting`` object, the nested ``recurring_meeting`` field is not updated, but a new   ``recurring_meeting`` is created instead. Not sure if it has do anything with your solution, just asking if it is related anyhow...

Comment: @Galil I didn't think about the update and delete case. I don't have pc around right now, so I can't test the solution. But you can try just exclude the  `recurring_meeting` field from json on update call and add `required=False` to the  `RecurringMeetingSerializer`, so you'll skip `to_internal_value` call on it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case instead of using a `RecurringMeetingRelatedField` in the Meeting serializer, you could define a nested serializer like this.

```
class RecurringMeetingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    interval = serializers.CharField()
    repetitions = serializers.IntegerField()
    weekdays_only = serializers.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'


class MeetingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    recurring_meeting = RecurringMeetingSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        exclude = ['object_id', 'content_type']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recurring_meeting = validated_data.pop('recurring_meeting')

        if recurring_meeting['interval'] == 'daily':
            instance = DailyMeeting.objects.create(**recurring_meeting)
            type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
        else:
            instance = WeeklyMeeting.objects.create(**recurring_meeting)
            type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)

        meeting = Meeting.objects.create(content_type=type,
                                         object_id=instance.id)

        return meeting
```