# How to manage writable nested serializers with multiple serializers in an unique field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working on django rest framework with nested serializers and i need support on how to POST an object that can take different type of models.

A good sketch is better than a long speech

I want to post this:

```
{
    "md5": "365v4a9e8fv4s9efb8",
    "computer": "computer_name",
    "branch": "git_branch",
    "planKey": "Key",
    "buildNumber": 25,
    "pullRequest": false,
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "name of the app",
            "project": "name of project",
            "mode": "release"
            ...
        },
        {
            "name": "name of the app",
            "project": "name of project",
            "mode": "release"
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Or this:

```
{
    "md5": "365v4a9e8fv4s9efb8",
    "computer": "computer_name",
    "branch": "git_branch",
    "planKey": "Key",
    "buildNumber": 25,
    "pullRequest": false,
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "name of the test",
            "status": "fail",
            "test_suite": "BB"
            ...
        },
        {
            "name": "name of the test",
            "status": "pass",
            "test_suite": "AA"
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

In both case, i want the same first top level model that is JobResult. But for the result field i want to be able to give the first model (Build) or the second one (Test)

models.py:

```
class JobResult(models.Model):
    md5 = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    computer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    planKey = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    buildNumber = models.IntegerField()
    pullRequest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Generic Relation between JobResult and (Daily or Test)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='result',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    result_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...


class Build(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    job_id = GenericRelation(JobResult, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_suite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_id = GenericRelation(JobResult, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I have tried to use generic foreignKey as you can see and referred to this post:
[Django Rest Framework: Writable nested serializers with Generic Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477489/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers-with-generic-foreign-key)

i don't really know if I'm doing right or not. I'm quiet lost with all the post and answer we can get from stack overflow or google. I don't know where to go from know...

i won't show my serializers.py because it's the same as the link referred above with modification for my models.

Last but not least. I already did a writable nested serializers from the django rest frammework docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ and it did work. i was able to POST a json with the build model.

So what should I do ? Am I going right ? Can anyone tell me where to look for this king of things ?

Don't hesitate to tell me if i'm totally mistaken. i'm quiet new to this.

Comment: I am with the exactly problem as you but I can't find answer anywhere. I managed to pass the only one nested value with a work around but not with multiple dictionaries. If I find the answer I will post here.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by referring to methodfield in parent serializer and for its get method you can call the child serializer of other model related to the same:

```
class SubSubjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    topics = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    sub_subject_id = serializers.CharField(source='id')

    class Meta:
      model = Subsubject
        fields = [
        'sub_subject_id',
        'title',
        'slug',
        'topics'
        ]

    def get_topics(self, obj):
       qs = obj.topics.all().order_by('id')
       return TopicListSerializer(qs, many=True, read_only=True).data


  class SubjectDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     sub_subjects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
      model = Subject
      fields = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'short_name',
        'icon_file',
        'contents',
        'slug',
        'image',
        'is_block',
        'status',
        'created_on',
        'created_by',
        'updated_on',
        'updated_by',
        'meta_description',
        'meta_keywords',
        'head_script',
        'sub_subjects',

    ]

  def get_sub_subjects(self, obj):
    return SubSubjectListSerializer(obj.sub_subjects.exclude(title='Others') 
                                         many=True).data
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So how about your models.py what do you use it ? I was referencing generic foreign key ? Does my models a good start ?

Comment: i am just using the foreign key for the parent objects and i think that will be a proper method for this.

Comment: As I can see in the documentation and in your answer, you can not post as I want. SerializerMethodField is just read only ? Where is the nested serializers to post ?